# Why does collectIsPressedAsState() not detect a press on a short tap inside a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-coordinatorlayout

In Jetpack Compose, I want to change the color of a custom text button depending on its pressed state.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val view = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
        setContentView(view)

        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            CustomTextButton()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomTextButton() {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val color = when (isPressed) {
        true -> Color.Red
        false -> Color.Black
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = isPressed) {
        println("#### isPressed: $isPressed")
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                onClick = { println("#### Box clicked") }
            )
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "CustomTextButton",
            color = color
        )
    }
}
```

The `CustomTextButton` is put in a `ComposeView` that is wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Unfortunately this only works for longer presses. On a short tap `isPressed` does not change to `true`. Consequently the Button's text color does not change.

The output on a longer press:

```
2023-02-17 13:31:22.598   ...  #### isPressed: true
2023-02-17 13:31:23.047   ...  #### Box clicked
2023-02-17 13:31:23.106   ...  #### isPressed: false
```

The output on a short tap:

```
2023-02-17 13:33:12.382   ...  #### Box clicked
```

After some more research I think I found the reason for this behavior. The compose devs added a delay if the ComposeView is inside a scrollable container.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203141462

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. This code works

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was checking again: My problem occurs only if there's a wrapping CoordinatorLayout around a ComposeView with the CustomTextButton. I will update my question.